# Laravel Group by day, month or year

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a new Laravel developer. I would like to group transactions by either month, day or year and receive a response like this

```
[
   {
      "year":"2020",
      "payments":[
         {},
         {},
         {}
      ]
   },
   {
      "year":"2021",
      "payments":[
         {},
         {},
         {}
      ]
   },
   {
      "year":"2022",
      "payments":[
         {},
         {},
         {}
      ]
   ]
```

Here is my Database Table Structure
[image: Payments Table Structure]

[image: Payments Table Structure]

Sample JSON RESPONSE DATA

```
  {
                    "id": 4,
                    "created_at": "2022-07-13T09:45:17.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-07-13T09:46:26.000000Z",
                    "MerchantRequestID": "61141-59440291-1",
                    "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_13072022124515847712695820",
                    "ResponseCode": "0",
                    "ResponseDescription": "Success. Request accepted for processing",
                    "CustomerMessage": "Success. Request accepted for processing",
                    "Amount": "50",
                    "PhoneNumber": "254712695820",
                    "PolicyGuid": "mshua_individual",
                    "TransactionDate": "20191219102115",
                    "MpesaReceiptNumber": "NLJ7RT61SV",
                    "Status": "paid",
                    "UserId": "7ef6866b-e8d0-4bb2-a646-c782860408b3"
                },
```

Comment: without actual data to work on we cannot really help you. Adding some data along with your `table`s structure would help us figure out a way to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question. I hope it will help

Comment: @ths I hope it will help